# Erratic behavior with gzip on unix

Tags: linux, unix, gzip, operations

I am compressing log files daily and very recently I have been seeing some crazy results on the file type of the file after compression.

Normally you would expect 
file 'filename.gz' returning gzip compressed data and some info on the file,
but on many files I am seeing just "data", "raw G3 data, byte-padded", "DBase 3 index file" random stuff.

Any issues anyone could think of that could be causing this? I can't decompress the file then because it is not recognized as a gzip file

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com would be better places, please request migration.

Comment: I suspect an error is occurring during the compression, resulting in an invalid file.